# LNK error (Unresolved External symbol) when trying to use a struct in a class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Hello I am getting a LNK error in the following code. I expect I am doing something wrong with the use of a class and struct together but can not find out what is wrong. I have seen people define structs outside a class then use instances of that struct in the class like I am trying to do here. I have also seen people use structs within the class itself but I thought in this case this made more sense.

The total error code is:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::vector<struct table,class std::allocator > tableOrder::TablesInUse" (?TablesInUse@tableOrder@@2V?$vector@Utable@@V?$allocator@Utable@@@std@@@std@@A)

I don't really understand why what I am trying to do would obfuscate anything to do with tables in use from the compiler.

my main file is

```
#include"CashRegister.h"
#include"TableOrder.h"
#include<iostream>
#include "order.h"



using namespace std;

int main() {
    tableOrder bigOrder;
    cout << bigOrder.TablesInUse.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

TableOrder.h is

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


struct table {
    unsigned int tableNumber;
    unsigned int numChairs;
    unsigned int numberOfPeople;
    bool occupied;

    //table();

    void toggleOccupied() {
        if (occupied == true) {
            occupied = false;
        }
        else
        {
            occupied = true;
        }
    }

    bool getTableOccupied() {
        return occupied;
    }

    void setNumChairs(int newChairNum) {
        numChairs = newChairNum;
    }

    void setTableNumber(int assignTableNum) {
        tableNumber = assignTableNum;
    }

     int getTablenumber() {
        return tableNumber;
    }

     int getNumberOfChairs() {
        return numChairs;
    }

    void setNumberOfPeople(int addNumPeople) {
        numberOfPeople = addNumPeople;
    }


};





class tableOrder {
public:

    tableOrder();
    
    int getSP() {
        return SP;
    }

    enum ServingProgress {
        seated,
        drinksOrder,
        starters,
        main,
        dessert,
        bill
    };

    ServingProgress SP = seated;

    std::string progress;

    void getCurrentProgress() {
        switch (SP) {
        case 0:
            progress = "seated";
            break;
        case 1:
            progress = "drinksOrder";
            break;
        case 2:
            progress = "starters";
            break;
        case 3:
            progress = "main";
            break;
        case 4:
            progress = "dessert";
            break;
        case 5:
            progress = "bill";
            break;
        }
    }

    void ProgressOrder() {
        switch (SP) {
        case 0:
            SP = drinksOrder;
            break;
        case 1:
            SP = starters;
            break;
        case 2:
            SP = main;
            break;
        case 3:
            SP = dessert;
            break;
        case 4:
            SP = dessert;
            break;
        case 5:
            SP = bill;
            progress = "finished";
            break;
        }
    }

    void checkForTablesInUse() {
        for (int i(0); i < allTables.size(); i++) {
            if (allTables[i].occupied) {
                TablesInUse.push_back(allTables[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    void checkForTablesNotInUse() {
        for (int i(0); i < TablesInUse.size(); i++) {
            if (TablesInUse[i].occupied == false) {
                TablesInUse.erase(TablesInUse.begin() + i);
            }
        }
    }

    void updateTablesInUse() {
        checkForTablesInUse();
        checkForTablesNotInUse();
    }

    table& getTable(unsigned int tableIndex) {
        return allTables[tableIndex - 1];
    }

    //instantiate tables
    table table_1 = { 1,6,0,false };
    table table_2 = { 2,5,0,false };
    table table_3 = { 3,4,0,false };
    table table_4 = { 4,8,0,false };
    table table_5 = { 5,4,0,false };


//protected:

    unsigned int assignedTableNumber;

    table assignedTable;

    static vector<table> availableTables;
    static vector<table> TablesInUse;
    static vector<table> TablesToSelect;
    static vector<table>  allTables;

};
```

and TableOrder.cpp is

```
#include "TableOrder.h"

tableOrder::tableOrder() {
     assignedTableNumber = 0;

     assignedTable = table_1;
    

    vector<table> availableTables = { table_1 };
    vector<table> TablesInUse = { table_1 };
    vector<table> TablesToSelect = { table_1 };
    vector<table> allTables = {table_1,table_2,table_3,table_4,table_5};
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What command are you using to compile this code?

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `availableTables`, `TablesInUse`, `TablesToSelect` and `allTables` as static members of `tableOrder`, but you don't define them. What you have done is define *local* variables in the `tableOrder` constructor.

You would need to add a few lines in `TableOrder.cpp`, at the global scope defining the variables, and then changing the code in the tableOrder constructor to assign the data you're trying to use to it; so something like:

```
vector<table> tableOrder::availableTables,
    tableOrder::TablesInUse,
    tableOrder::TablesToSelect,
    tableOrder::allTables;

tableOrder::tableOrder() {
     assignedTableNumber = 0;

     assignedTable = table_1;


    availableTables = { table_1 };
    TablesInUse = { table_1 };
    TablesToSelect = { table_1 };
    allTables = {table_1,table_2,table_3,table_4,table_5};
}
```

> Although, I don't quite get initializing the static members in the tableOrder constructor - is it supposed to be a singleton?

Comment: Hello @AnyaShenanigans thanks for the help and the explanation. No it wasn't supposed to be a singleton I just thought that was the normal way to do it haha.

Answer (score 1):

The [Static Member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) `tableOrder::TableInUse`, although declared in `TableOrder.h`, was never defined.

The same applies to the 3 other static members of `tableOrder`.

In `TableOrder.cpp`, in `tableOrder::tableOrder()` you have 4 automatic variables named the same as the aforementioned static members. I think what you probably meant to do, which should also solve the problem, was:

```
#include "TableOrder.h"

std::vector tableOrder::availableTables;
std::vector tableOrder::TablesInUse;
std::vector tableOrder::TablesToSelect;
std::vector tableOrder::allTables;

tableOrder::tableOrder() {
    ...

    availableTables = { table_1 };
    TablesInUse = { table_1 };
    TablesToSelect = { table_1 };
    allTables = {table_1,table_2,table_3,table_4,table_5};
}
```